# Excel VBA Copy and Paste to Multiple Sheets Based on Conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I need Excel VBA code that will help me automate the following:

I need to be able to copy and paste rows from a "master" worksheet to multiple newly created worksheets based on the data found in Column "K" with a header called "Skill". If Column K has any of the following "DEL-LPT-PRECISN", "DEL-LPT-XPS", "DEL-LT-ALIENWARE", "DEL-PC-AIO-OPTI", "DEL-PC-AIO-XPS", "DEL-PC-PRECISION" copy the entire row to newly created worksheet "Hard" If column "K" has anything else move it to newly created workshieet "Easy"

The column headers should be the same from the master to the 2 newly created wks "easy" and "hard"

The master worksheet changes daily and can have anywhere from 200 to 500 rows of data.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using advance filters. Or you can write a macro to filter for each criteria, and copy/paste accordingly.

Or you can use this less efficient code.

Assumptions:

1. You already have 3 sheets named "Master", "Hard", "Easy" on your workbook
2. Each sheet has headers
3. All headers are identical

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveData()

Dim Master As Worksheet: Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim Hard As Worksheet: Set Hard = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hard")
Dim Easy As Worksheet: Set Easy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Easy")

Dim String1, String2, String3, String4, String5, String6 As String
String1 = "DEL-LPT-PRECISN"
String2 = "DEL-LPT-XPS"
String3 = "DEL-LT-ALIENWARE"
String4 = "DEL-PC-AIO-OPTI"
String5 = "DEL-PC-AIO-XPS"
String6 = "DEL-PC-PRECISION"

Dim MyCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In Master.Range("K2:K" & Master.Range("K" & Master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If MyCell.Text = String1 Or MyCell.Text = String2 Or MyCell.Text = String3 Or MyCell.Text = String4 Or MyCell.Text = String5 Or MyCell.Text = String6 Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy Hard.Range("A" & Hard.Range("A" & Hard.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)
        Else
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy Easy.Range("A" & Easy.Range("A" & Easy.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)
        End If
    Next MyCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello udearboy! Thank you so much for taking the time in helping me with my problem. I executed your code and received a "Compile error: Variable not defined" error message with cell highlighted in the 1st cell.EntireRow.Copy Hard.Range(......

Comment: try defining `cell` as range.

Comment: good evening excelguy! thanks for your respose. I defined cell as range and now I get "Run-time error 91" Object or With block variable not set" with the following hightlighted 'cell.EntireRow.Copy Easy.Range("A" & Easy.Range("A" & Easy.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)'

Comment: Updated. The search range was only defined to one cell. Changed `For Each MyCell in Master.Range("K2:K" & .....)` Sorry about that